# How to filter an image with dominant color of neighborhood in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to have a brush effect filter on a image with OpenCV. In order to accomplish that, program will go through each pixel and give it dominant color of neighborhood within a given radius. By dominant color, I mean not average or median but most frequent color. Is there any OpenCV API to do this?

Comment: There's no magic function to do that as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic function to do that as far as I know.